# How is memory allocated for typedef's in structs (C)

Tags: c, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

When you create a struct in C, for example:

```
typedef struct student
{

int roll_no;
char* name;
int* pointer;


}student;
```

I noticed that roll_no and name are not stored contiguously in memory. How does this work? If aim is to encapsulate this data, wouldn't it be better if they were stored contiguously? How does the compiler know that these pieces of data belong together?

Comment: Read [structure padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding). `typedef` only creates an alias for an `type`, it does not define a new data type.

Comment: [This answer on structure alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/119128/1887090) has a nice explanation and example.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler aligns the start of each element of a struct to match the requirements of the architecture.
This usually means alignment is on a on a word boundary, but there is no hard and fast rule.

typedef has no effect on alignment - it simply creates a "shorthand reference" to some object, maybe  like a struct.  You can think of typedefs as synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

The `name` is indeed not stored together with the `struct`: only a *pointer* to it is stored. The data is usually allocated dynamically in the area outside the `struct` itself.

To have the name stored together with the `struct` you need to make it an array. The downside to this approach is that either the string must be fixed length (i.e. all `struct`s will allocate the amount of memory sufficient for a `name` of max length, or you need to use a flexible array element by declaring the `name[]` array at the end of the `struct`. The downsides to this last approach is that (1) the allocation becomes a lot more complicated, (2) you cannot make an array of such `struct`s, and (3) you can have only one flexible array in a structure.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored contiguously. just that the address contained inside the char *name is somewhere else. To store contiguously in memory use a array instead of a pointer.

this is how it is stored in memory, for example, address for struct starts at 1000 (decimal).

```
1000 roll_no
1004 name
1008 pointer
```

name and pointer are pointer, so they will hold values (addresses) allocated by malloc.

```
s->name = malloc(100);
s->pointer = malloc(4);
```

In this case there is no structure padding, since all are ints (even pointers are), which means they are the size of the architecture's register sizes (usually 32 or 64 bits).

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored contiguously, however there may be wholes because of optimisations and alignment onto word boundaries. The alignment depends on the processor you are running on and compiler options selected. (packing)

The compiler will calculate the offsets into your structure, so it can do the lookups into memory to fetch the elements of your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the *struct*

```
struct student
{
  int roll_no;
  char* name;
  int* pointer;
}
```

C does exactly what you want (besides "structure padding" but this is another story). Assuming `gcc` on Intel processors, struct is made of

- 4 bytes of `int`, followed by
- 4 bytes of `char *` pointer to *name*, followed by
- 4 bytes of `int *` pointer to *pointer*

The *name* member is a pointer to char(s), usually pointer to a string of characters, somewhere in memory. For instance

```
char *string = "John Doe";
int value = 255;
struct student me;

me.roll_no = 15;
me.name = string;
me.pointer = &value;
```

here *string* is somewhere in memory - as you noticed it was declared far before the structure. Say its memory location is `0x12345678`, and *value* is at `0x20000000` and structure is at 0x22222222 so we have

```
0x12345678 : John Doe\0
...
0x20000000 : FF000000  // 255
...
0x22222222 : 0F0000001234567820000000
```

you see the structure is `0F000000` for `15`, `12345678` for *string* address and `20000000` for *value* address.

Comment: Ok so just checking if I've got it right. The roll_no, POINTER to the string name, and the address of the pointer itself are infact stored contiguously. The string itself is stored somewhere else in memory.Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The *string* itself and the *int* pointed to by *pointer* are somewhere else in memory.

Comment: When I did this: 
printf("%p\n%p\n%p",&s.roll_no, &s.name, &s.pointer);

The address of the roll_no, the address of the pointer to the string, and the address of the pointer were contiguous. But what you said now contradicts with this. According to you the **only the addresses of the pointers to the string and int are contiguous.**

Comment: *string* and *pointer* **are** pointers. What you did is display the addresses of the structure fields - they are of course contiguous. If you `printf("%p\n%p\n%p",&s.roll_no, s.name, s.pointer);` to display the address of *roll_no*, and the content of the *name* (where "John Doe" is) and *pointer* (where `255` is) pointers, you will see they're not contiguous. Look at my exemple above: your `printf` was like displaying `0x22222222`, `0x22222226` and `0x2222222A` which are contiguous..

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks a lot, you were really helpful! 
One final question - &s.name and s.pointer are the same right?

Comment: Hmm *s.name* and *s.pointer* are two different fields. `&s.name` gives the address of the *s.name* structure field, while *s.pointer* contains a pointer to an *int*.

Comment: Oh damn, I forgot to say that I had done this:

pointer = &s.roll_no

Got it! Thanks!